# Trying to assign a Grade using IF in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I'm trying to assign a `PASS/FAIL` grade to an item. The criteria are:

- If the `bit` has `>=60, bits >=5, bites >=3, bite >=250, widgets=new` the item will `PASS`
- otherwise if any of these are wrong the item will `FAIL`

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: I see from your public profile you did not take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I suggest you do so and then come back here, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52506461/edit) and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I did a search and took the tour, tried some things but they weren't returning what I needed. Everything returned PASS no matter what I did. Was hoping for some help.

Comment: In general, it is always better to mention what has already been tried so that we don't go over already covered ground.

Answer (score 2):

Under presumption you are referencing to data correctly:

```
=IF(AND(bit>=60, bits>=5, bites>=3, bite>=250, widgets="new"), "PASS", "FAIL")
```

> *But it's hard to tell, unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete and
>   Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and as
>   @cybernetic.nomad pointed out, it would be a good idea to take the
>   [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) while at it.*

Comment: Apologies I did try to give an example but it wouldn't format so that it was readable. I will give your formula a try, I've tried one similar to that but it didn't return what I needed. Again thank you for your help and apologies for the lack of providing examples.